# how do I loop through my data frame and change a value in each row depending on different value in the same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Movies dataset which I've converted into a data frame and then cleaned up.
This dataset contains the following columns:

```
['title_year', 'color', 'duration', 'language', 'country', 'budget', 'imdb_score', movie_facebook_likes', 'director_facebook_likes', 'cast_total_facebook_likes', 'gross']
```

The budget field (obviously) contains the movie's budget, but this budget is in its country of origin's currency.

My question is how do I loop through my data frame and change the budget value of each film depending on its country of origin?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to update the value of each movie budget based on the country of origin, To loop through the dataset you do this.
Assuming the dataset['title_year', 'color', 'duration', 'language', 'country', 'budget', 'imdb_score', movie_facebook_likes', 'director_facebook_likes', 'cast_total_facebook_likes', 'gross'] is A and the data set of countries budget will be B

```
for v in A:
    for x in B:
       if v_Country_key == x_Country_key and v_movie_key == x_movie_key:
          {v_Budget_key : x_Budget_value} #you update the budget in A with data from budget in B using dictionary
```

This should work, you are just updating the the movie dictionary with budget data from the countries dictionary